# Registering system-widehotkey in python 3

Tags: windows, python-3.x, hotkeys

im trying to find a way to register a hotkey in windows using python 3. I need to use python 3 because the python script im trying to modify uses python and so do all of its dependencies

I have tried googling around to find something, but I cant find anything that seems to work

I tried doing what it says on this website
http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/catch_system_wide_hotkeys.html

but pressing the hotkeys doesnt do anything

I just want to write a few simple bits of code which registers a hotkey and then runs a function when the hotkey is pressed